# Writing to Postgres table with duplicate keys via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy write to Postgres.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/mydb')
```

I want to append a pandas dataframe, `df`, to `table` in `mydb`.

Both have the same column names, `key` and `value`.

`key` is the primary key in `table`.

Some key values in `df` are already in `table`.

(1) Append fails:

```
df.to_sql('table',engine,if_exists='append')
```

This fails (`IntegrityError`) because some keys in `df` are already in `table`.

(2) I convert `df` to a record array and try writing to `table`:

```
conn = engine.connect()
query=''' insert or replace into table (key,value) values (?,?) '''
conn.executemany(query,df.to_records())
```

This works with sqlite ([Appending Pandas dataframe to sqlite table by primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574614/appending-pandas-dataframe-to-sqlite-table-by-primary-key)).

But, it fails here (`ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "or"`).

What's the right way to do this using postgres and sqlalchemy?

Comment: Won't the manual `executemany` with an `insert into` query also fail? (as in that case you will try inserting keys already in the table?)

Comment: Yes, you may be right: with `sqlite3` library, `insert or replace` in the query solves this problem with `conn.executemany()`. If I include `or replace` in the query here, I get an error: `ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "or". `

Comment: As far as I know, postgresql has no such feature to do an insert with update on duplicate values, see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Comment: Got it. What about performing the `insert` for each record in the array and catching the error when the key is present? That would solve the problem.

Comment: What you also can do is first read the keys from sql, then filter your dataframe to those rows that don't include any of these keys, and then write that filtered frame to sql.

Comment: Right. That's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the records and catching exceptions seems to be the best solution?

```
inp=df.to_records(index=True)
for i in inp: 
   q=''' insert into table (key,value) values %s '''%i
   try:
     conn.execute(q)
   except IntegrityError:
     print "Key in table."
```