# Python pandas to_sql violates foreign key constraint

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pandasql

How to catch `Traceback`, when inserting a `Dataframe` to a Djando model

I have two Django models, one model has data, in this case the `Customer` model

Sample models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
class Account(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField()
    ...
```

Account dataframe

```
try:
    df.to_sql('account', con=engine, if_exists='append')
except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as e:
    print(e)

psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table 
"account" violates foreign key constraint
```

I want to identify the rows of the dataframe that do not have the Foreign Key, and let the others be inserted

Comment: i think it can help you [insert by row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881631/8060120)