# Pandas .to_sql() throwing an error for duplicate entry

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, sqlalchemy

I am working on pandas dataframe concept to send the data on mysql server.

I have few .csv files eg. one.csv, two.csv. I am reading csv file in dataframe object and using SQLAlChemry library trying to send the file on mysql server

```
def db_write(db_config,contact_df):
    IP_ADDR=db_config["ip_addr"]
    PORT_NUMBER=db_config["port_num"]
    USER_NAME=db_config["user_name"]
    PASSWORD=db_config["password"]
    DATABASE_NAME=db_config["database_name"]
    TABLE_NAME=db_config["table_name"]

    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://"+USER_NAME+":"+PASSWORD+"@"+IP_ADDR+"/"+DATABASE_NAME)
    con = engine.connect()

    contact_df.to_sql(con=con, name=TABLE_NAME,if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I am sending **one.csv** file successfully on server but while sending two.csv on server I am getting IntegrityErro issue

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062,
> "Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' for key 'db.mobile_number'"

NOTE :-
having a schema where id has primary key and mobile_number has unique constraint and while sending second file data it might have chances that we may have some common data which is already availbe on server

**Question**

1. How to ignore the duplicate data to be insert in database using .to_sql() method
2. how to use the concept of *insert ignore* and *replace* of mysql in sqlalchemry

**What i have tried**
I have refereed below stacjoverflow question but it didnt worked
3. [Pandas to_sql fails on duplicate primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337394/pandas-to-sql-fails-on-duplicate-primary-key)
4. [Appending Pandas dataframe to sqlite table by primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574614/appending-pandas-dataframe-to-sqlite-table-by-primary-key)

Plz help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to create a new table?

Comment: Yes, I have all required credentials and permission

Comment: As far as I can see the `to_sql()` method doesn't have any option check for and skip duplicate keys https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html You could insert it into a temporary table with the `replace` option, and then for each file also create an insert statement into the actual destination table that takes into account for duplicates.

Comment: hi @BdR, any other solution in terms of SQLAlChemry library ??